# Java Swing: NullPointerException in own created resizable GUI

Tags: java, swing, nullpointerexception

First of all, I know using the `setLayout(null)` is not the best way, but the goal of that program was to try writing a GUI that is resizable by myself.

First of all, the three classes (the reason of splitting the `GroundFrame.java` and the `HomeScreen.java` is that in future there will be multiple windows):

**Start.java**

```
public class Start {

    public static void main(String[] arg){
        new GroundFrame();  
    }
}
```

**GroundFrame.java**

```
public class GroundFrame extends JFrame{

    static final long       serialVersionUID = 0;
    Container               contentPane;
    HomeScreen              homeScreen;

    public GroundFrame(){
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                createAndShowGUI();
            }
        });
    }

    private void createAndShowGUI(){
        createBasicFrame();
        createPaneAndAddHome();
        setVisible(true);
    }

    private void createBasicFrame(){
        addComponentListener(new ComponentListener() {
            public void componentShown(ComponentEvent e) {}
            public void componentResized(ComponentEvent e) {
                homeScreen.resizeHome(getContentPane().getSize());
            }
            public void componentMoved(ComponentEvent e) {}
            public void componentHidden(ComponentEvent e) {}
        });

        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        contentPane = getContentPane();
        contentPane.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(600, 400));
        contentPane.setLayout(null);
        pack();
    }

    private void createPaneAndAddHome(){
        homeScreen = new HomeScreen(contentPane.getSize());
        contentPane.add(homeScreen);
    }
}
```

**HomeScreen.java**

```
public class HomeScreen extends JPanel{

    static final long       serialVersionUID = 0;
    private JLabel          labelHeader, labelFooter;
    private JTextField      textField;
    private int             x, y;

    public HomeScreen(final Dimension dimension){
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                createAndShowPanel(dimension);
            }
        });
    }

    private void createAndShowPanel(Dimension dimension){
        labelHeader = new JLabel("HEADER");
        textField = new JTextField();
        labelFooter = new JLabel("FOOTER");
        setupPanel(dimension);
    }

    private void setupPanel(Dimension dimension){
        x = dimension.width;
        y = dimension.height;
        setBounds(0,0,x,y);
        setLayout(null);
        setupTitle(new Dimension(x,y));
    }

    private void setupTitle(Dimension dimension){
        x = dimension.width;
        y = dimension.height;
        labelHeader.setBounds((int)(x*0.1), (int)(y*0.1), (int)(x*0.8), (int)(y*0.3));
        labelHeader.setOpaque(true);
        labelHeader.setBackground(Color.cyan);
        labelHeader.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.PLAIN, (int)(y*0.25)));

        textField.setBounds((int)(x*0.25), (int)(y*0.45), (int)(x*0.5), (int)(y*0.1));
        textField.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.PLAIN, (int)(y*0.08)));

        labelFooter.setBounds((int)(x*0.1), (int)(y*0.6), (int)(x*0.8), (int)(y*0.3));
        labelFooter.setOpaque(true);
        labelFooter.setBackground(Color.cyan);
        labelFooter.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.PLAIN, (int)(y*0.25)));

        add(labelHeader);
        add(labelFooter);
        add(textField);
    }

    public void resizeHome(Dimension dimension){
        setupPanel(dimension);
    }
}
```

Now everything works as I had in mind, but I'm getting a `NullpointerException` at following line in `HomeScreen.java`

```
labelHeader.setBounds((int)(x*0.1), (int)(y*0.1), (int)(x*0.8), (int)(y*0.3));
```

This is the error message

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at gui.HomeScreen.setupTitle(HomeScreen.java:45)
    at gui.HomeScreen.setupPanel(HomeScreen.java:39)
    at gui.HomeScreen.resizeHome(HomeScreen.java:64)
    at gui.GroundFrame$2.componentResized(GroundFrame.java:43)
    at java.awt.AWTEventMulticaster.componentResized(AWTEventMulticaster.java:159)
    at java.awt.Component.processComponentEvent(Component.java:6331)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6285)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2229)
    at java.awt.Window.processEvent(Window.java:2022)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4861)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2287)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2719)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4687)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:703)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$000(EventQueue.java:102)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:662)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:660)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:87)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:676)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:674)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:673)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:244)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:163)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:151)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:147)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:139)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:97)
```

Nonetheless, the program continues to run as nothing happened. After all, the error appears when the program starts, so at a point where no manually resize is performed (The error message indicates that the error is called among others from the `HomeScreen`s `resizeHome()`). Why is this so? Why does the program continues to run? Is it possible that the building of the GUI itself is a first call of the `ComponentListener`s `componentResized()`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because you are using `SwingUtilities#invokeLater` in your constructors

```
SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        createAndShowGUI();
    }
});
```

What you've created is a race condition within you UI.

Basically, `homeScreen.resizeHome` is being called (from `componentResized`) BEFORE `HomeScreen#createAndShowPanel` is called, thus meaning that the `lablelHeader` has not yet being initalised...

Your current sequence of events look something like...

- main
- `new GrounFrame()`
- `invokeLater` `GroundFrame#createAndShowGUI`
- ... (return to main)
- `GroundFrame#createBasicFrame` (add `ComponentListener`, `pack`)
- `GroundFrame#createPaneAndAddHome`
- `new HomeScreen`
- `invokeLater` `HomeScreen#createAndShowPanel` ... return immediately...
- `GrounFrame#setVisible(true)`
- `GrounFrame#ComponentListener#componentResized`
- `HomeScreen#resizeHome`
- `HomeScreen#setupPanel`
- `Null Pointer Exception`
- `HomeScreen#createAndShowPanel`

You should sync your UI with the EDT within your `main`

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            new GroundFrame();
        }
    });
}
```

And remove the other references to `SwingUtilities#invokeLater`